# Magento 2 : How to place order with klarna using graphql?

Tags: magento2, klarna

I have enabled the below modules in Magento/2.4 (Enterprise) &
configured klarna on the backend with a sandbox account.

```
Module 'Klarna_Core':
Module 'Klarna_Ordermanagement':
Module 'Klarna_Kp':
Module 'Klarna_KpGraphQl':
```

Place order from default Magento is working but I am not sure about the graphql mutation required to place an order with klarna using graphql.

need some advice on it.

Comment: Klarna payment method is already bundled with Magento 2. You can check it at Stores > configuration > Payment Methods.

Comment: You just need klarna API username and API password

Comment: @Pawan I have found that below module are already their but not enabled.

'Klarna_Core'
'Klarna_Ordermanagement' 
'Klarna_Kp' 
'Klarna_Onsitemessaging' 
'Klarna_KpGraphQl' 

Not sure which module is responsible for payment.
what are your thoughts ?

Comment: in current setup i work on has react based frontend & magento

Comment: I haven't use Klarna But 'Klarna_Core' and 'Klarna_Kp' are the required module. are you using Rest API for fetching data ?

Comment: no graphql mutations @Pawan

Comment: if you are using "graphql",  `Klarna_KpGraphQl` module will be sufficient.they already provide support for `graphql`

Comment: Correct thanks for the advice @Pawan

Comment: welcome :), I added my comment as an answer as well.

Comment: @Pawan i just want the klarna graphql & klarna payment method to be enabled, could you please advice which modules can i enable ?

Comment: If you check "vendor/klarna/module-kp-graph-ql/etc/module.xml" file, `Klarna_KpGraphQl` is depends on `Klarna_Kp` so you need to enable both module.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: For Test payment method, anybody needs credential to check. I will try to check it.

Comment: @Pawan

I have checked on this,
executed steps for place order using klarna method with graphql

Getting 405 Method Not Allowed error

It looks like it requires "authorization_token" used when creating the order 
On FE that is created on click place order button.


That's why error is appeared, i have checked further & found that its fetched using js
call

https://developers.klarna.com/documentation/klarna-payments/integration-guide/authorize/

Comment: Magento2/vendor/klarna/module-kp/Model/Api/Rest/Service/Payments.php
line 211

placeOrder method which is used.

Comment: @Pawan i am not sure how to generate or get the auth token from klarna
as its working from frontend as it fetch token with javascript calls on place order click event.
but not sure how to get it with graphql.

Comment: https://developers.klarna.com/documentation/testing-environment/
here to create test accont klarna

Comment: Sure, I will try this.

Comment: Thankyou very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Klarna payment method is already bundled with magento 2. You can check it at

> Stores > configuration > Payment Methods

You just need `klarna API username` and `API password`

**Note:** If you are using "graphql", `Klarna_KpGraphQl` module will be sufficient.

Magento/klarna, already provide support for graphql

Answer (score 1):

To install the module it's like all other magento module, either you get the code from an archive and you can just paste it to your code, either your have the access with composer and install it to the vendor.

Once installed, all the configuration process seems to be in the magento 2 official documentation : https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/klarna-setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Below mutations needs to be executed for place order using klarna
it also need the order to be authorized that will be done on client side.

Step 1 - `createEmptyCart`

Step 2 - `addProductsToCart`

Step 3 - `setGuestEmailOnCart`

Step 4 - `setShippingAddressesOnCart`

Step 5 - `setBillingAddressOnCart`

Step 6 - `setShippingMethodsOnCart`

Step 7 - `createKlarnaPaymentsSession`

Step 8 - `Authorize the order to klarna api`

Step 9 - `setPaymentMethodOnCart`

Step 10 - `placeOrder`